# com.Connection = con; it is showing wrong

Tags: c#

## //it is show the connection string  con.connection wrong .it is not accepted

```
string con =(string) ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
//string con = Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString;
string sql = "SELECT category.Id, category.category, book.bookid FROM category INNER JOIN  book ON category.Id ="+m;
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
com.CommandText = sql;
com.Connection = con;

con.Open()
{
    com.EndExecuteNonQuery()
    con.close;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please describe your problem a little more: is there an exception or a compile-time error?

Answer (score 4):

The `Connection` property is a [SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), while your variable `con` holds a [string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Here's how you could make it work:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(con))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // your logic to process the response
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `con.Open()` isn't right either. You might want to put the the connection creation in the first line, and assign it to con.

Comment: @hatchet indeed, I updated the code block to be more complete

Comment: good on ya for adding the usings too.